# What’s the meaning of ‘go on’ here?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

‘Go on’ has a lot of meanings in dictionaries, which makes me confused. What’s the omitted words and meanings of ‘go on’ in the following scene?

(They are gambling on a sport in the magical world.)

> ”I’ve already got Roddy Pontner betting me Bulgaria will score first – I offered him nice odds, considering Ireland’s front three are the strongest I’ve seen in years – and little Agatha Timms has put up half shares in her eel farm on a week-long match.”
>
> ”Oh … go on then,” said Mr. Weasley. “Let’s see … a Galleon on Ireland to win?”

(*Harry Potter 4* [US Version]: p.88)

Comment: -Thanks. Both of your answers gave me an inspiration. What the first speaker said virtually means “Could I invite you to a bet?”, didn’t it? In a manner of speaking, my question seems to be a matter of context, not of a phrasal verb. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Go on* can mean *please proceed* or *go ahead and do it*. This this case, it may mean "Oh... please proceed and make the bet then," said Mr. Weasley.

There is also a British informal use of *go on* that means *you can't be serious* in a bashful or embarrassed tone.

Comment: Oh, I see. I sometimes see that ‘go on’ in _Harry Potter_ books. Great. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

There is no missing word, the ... is just a pause.

"Oh … go on then" means "Ok, I'm persuaded to do it"